# Enable reverse proxy after Service Fabric cluster is created

Tags: proxy, reverse, azure-service-fabric

We have an Azure-hosted SF cluster instance, with a bunch of services already in production.

We would like to enable the reverse proxy in order for it to be utilized for services intra-communication as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy (since it was not enabled during cluster deployment).

Is there any way this is feasible?

Answer (score 1):

You could just update your ARM template with the Reverse Proxy settings and than redeploy the cluster. [Upgrade domains](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description.md) should help you out on keeping your services available.